# What I can use to determine if the number is Prime or Not without using Boolean?

Tags: java, primes

Our Professor gave us a bunch of problems to program. I'm almost done until I read that my last assignment to program, we can't use Boolean and "for". What can I use aside from "for" and "Boolean" to determine if the number is Prime or Not? I hope someone will notice this. Help me, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The very question "if" implies a boolean, if only as the return value, so I'm not quite sure what you mean. But it sounds like your professor might be suggesting that you use recursion. (Generally, when a professor asks you to do something that you'd normally do iteratively, but doesn't let you use a for or while loop, they're thinking about recursion.) On the other hand, a recursive algorithm requires separating the base cases from the others, which is an if/else, which requires boolean logic... so, I dunno.

Comment: It says, we can use "if". Do you know what is the formula to get the prime number without using "for"?

Answer (score 2):

A way to solve it without `for` is by using recursion. If the use of conditionals does not count as a boolean use I think this is an answer to the exercise:

```
public String verify(int num) {
  if (num <= 1) {
    return IS_NOT_PRIME; 
  }
  if (num )
    return isPrime(num, num);
  }
}

public String isPrime(int i, int num) {
  if (i == 1) {
    return IS_PRIME;
  }
  if (num % i == 0 && i != num) {
    return IS_NOT_PRIME; 
  }
  return isPrime(i-1, num);
}
```

edit: English, lint and negative numbers fix. Pointed out by Tommy.

Comment: This program will give you a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` for negative numbers.

Comment: Also (traditionally) `Strings` are not supposed to start with underscores. They are written in camelCase(such as `isPrime` and `notPrime`, rather than `_IS` and `_ISNT`. You can capitalize `Strings` if they are `final` if you want, such as `IS_PRIME` and `NOT_PRIME`.

Comment: That's true, what would be a good approach, return `_IS` when the number can be divided by 4 numbers?  `-13  {-13, -1, 1, 13}.`

Comment: Actually all negative numbers are prime, according to it's [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=prime+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=active&q=prime+number+definition): _"A prime number is a whole number **greater than 1**, whose only two whole-number factors are 1 and itself. "_ All you have to do is make it return `_IS` when the number is negative

Comment: Whole numbers does not include negatives @Tommy

Comment: hmm... I guess you're right. What is it then? So negative integers are not prime? Your answer is good though. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop instead of a for-loop, like this:

```
public class Prime{
    static int i = 2;
    public static String prime(int n){
        if(n <= 0){
            return("Please enter a  number greater than 0");
        }
        while(i < n){
            if(n % i == 0){
                return(n + " is not prime");
            }
            i++;
        }
        return (n + " is prime");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to check any possibility the response is always in form of `boolean`.

If he is very specific about return `data type` not being `boolean` then you can return `int` (1 or 0).

Alternatives to `for loop` are `while`, `do-while` or `recursion`.

Alternative to `iterative` structures is `recursion`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program of checking prime number without using boolean and for loop:

```
public class PrimeNumber {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber();
    int i = 2; 
    int num = 3;    
    if (num <= 1) {
        System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number"); 
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    while(i <= Math.sqrt(num)) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
        System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number");
                System.exit(1);
        }
     i++;
    }
    System.out.println(num + " is a prime number");      
 }  }
```